# Restriction of Direct access in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form page called `form.php` and when it is submitted it goes to `step.php`.

Now if users directly go to `step.php` it should go to `error.php`.

I tried a code but it also goes to `error.php` when user is redirected from `form.php'

The code which I tried:-

```
<?php
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', TRUE, 403 );
    die( header( 'location: error.php' ) );

}
?>
```

Comment: May be use $_SESSION or cookie to store information about form submit?

Comment: can you help with the code..?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `POST` not `GET` or how are you submitting your form?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone `POST` is not doing any thing

Comment: What method is your form sending as? What do your two `realpath` variables return and are they expected? What debugging have you done if any?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone **<?php
if ( isset($_POST['cnor'] )) {
 // the form was submitted
    if ( isset( $_POST['cno']) ) {
     // we have data to validate
  if ( $_POST['cno'] == 'mkjain' ) {
         echo '<FRAMESET border=0 rows="100%,*" frameborder="no" marginleft=0 margintop=0 marginright=0 marginbottom=0>
<frame src="password.php" scrolling=auto frameborder="no" border=0 noresize>
<frame topmargin="0" marginwidth=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 frameborder="no" border=0 noresize>
</FRAMESET>';
        }
  else {
         echo 'Invalid User Id.';
        }
    }
}
?>**

Comment: That's not the form... What method are you using to send your form as... Plus same questions as last time again...

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I have written full code as my answer please refer it.

Comment: Why have you put that as an answer? Edit the original question... I still haven't received answers to my 3 questions...

Comment: I wrote in **answers** column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149127/discussion-between-shrisun-and-peter-featherstone).

Comment: @ShriSun - it is not an answer, please remove it... And for the 4th time, what does a `var_dump` of your two `realpath` variables come back as?

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. If you have any new information to add, edit your original post and add the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session to store information about form submit.

Place

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['was_on_form'] = 1;
```

on the top of form.php, and

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['was_on_form'])) {
     // show error or make redirect
}
```

on the top of step.php

But usually it is not problem, that user visit step.php before form.php. In step.php you just validate $_POST form data and if data valid it is ok to proceed.

Comment: @ShriSun do not edit answers provided for your questions. The PHP opening and closing tags are not necessary in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Solution  1

form.php

get the name of the button to submit to step.php

step.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
   // button submitted
}
else{
  // button not submitted
}

?>
```

Solution 2

create a session on form.php with a unique value and store it as a hidden value

form.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['inputToken'] = rand(4 , 100); // you can generate a random string of your own rand() function is for numbers
$token = $_SESSION['inputToken'];
?>
<form>
<input type='hidden' name='_token' value='$token'/>
<input type='submit' name='btn_submit' value=''/>
</form>
```

step.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']) AND isset($_POST['_token']))
{
   // check token if valid

   if($_POST['_token'] == $_SESSION['inputToken'])
    {
      // submitted from the form 
    }
    else{
      // form was not submitted

      header("location:form.php?msg=1");
    }

}
else{
  // button not submitted
  header("location:form.php?msg=2");
}

?>
```

Comment: I used **solution2** but then also I can go to `step.php` directly

Comment: l have edited solution 2 the answer check if it works

Comment: I tried, now it does not goes to `step.php` **but** it also not goes when form is filled and button is submitted